# Escaping single quote in String.Format()

Tags: .net, escaping, string.format

I have been all over the 'tubes and I can't figure this one out. Might be simple.

The following `String.Format` call:

```
return dt.ToString("MMM d yy 'at' H:mmm");
```

Correctly returns this:

> Sep 23 08 at 12:57

Now let's say I want to add a single quote before the year, to return this:

> Sep 23 '08 at 12:57

Since the single quote is a reserved escape character, **how do I escape the single quote to get it to display?**

I have tried double, triple, and quad single quotes, with no luck.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can escape it using a backslash which you will have to escape. Either

```
return dt.ToString(@"MMM d \'yy 'at' H:mmm");
```

or

```
return dt.ToString("MMM d \\'yy 'at' H:mmm");
```

Comment: in my defense, I became mesmerized by the way you have to do {{{ to escape curlies in a `String.Format()` and temporarily lost my mind.. thanks!

Comment: The % characters are unnecessary in this case as %d and %H are combined with other format patterns. It makes it a bit clearer without them.

Comment: @Martin I don't know if this is related or if I should open a new question, but how can I make this work? `<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("MyDate", "{0:MMM d yy 'at' H:mmm}")%>'>` currently I get an error, I guess because the sigle quotes of 'at'

Comment: nevermind, I found the solution here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264414/how-to-use-single-quotes-in-eval-format-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264414/how-to-use-single-quotes-in-eval-format-string)

Answer (score 5):

You could just use the HTML entity, if it's for HTML.

-- Edit

```
&#39;
```

-- Edit

Just to make this post not wrong, as everyone else has noted, escaping works fine :)

```
string s = t.ToString("MMM d \\'yy 'at' H:mmm");
```

And that's the last time I don't test something based on who is posting :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the C# @ strings unless I really have to use them so I would actually go with this.

```
return dt.ToString("MMM d \\'yy 'at' H:mmm");
```

It's just a preference though for which you find easier to "read".

Comment: Try writing a unit test that tests a class that detects escaped characters and processes them.  You'll start loving @ strings in a big hurry.

Comment: After 5 minutes writing regexes, I started to love @ strings too. :-)