# VS consider ' as a comment note formula

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel-interop

I am trying to open a excel file in vb.net with excel interop 
then add a formula to F2 then save as excel as csv

Can someone point me how to concatenate an ' with number in a formula cs when i write ' the Visual studio consider it as a comment not a formula

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim newFileName As String = "Libanpost" + Date.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".csv"
    Dim oExcelFile As Object



    Try
        oExcelFile = GetObject("c:\database", "Excel.Application")
    Catch
        oExcelFile = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End Try

    oExcelFile.Visible = True
    Dim strfilename As String = "Libanpost" + Date.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".xls"
    Dim strFolderPath As String = "c:\database"

    oExcelFile.Workbooks.Open(strFolderPath + "\" + strfilename)
    Dim oExcelsheet As Excel.Worksheet
    oExcelsheet = oExcelFile.sheets("table1")
    oExcelsheet.Range("f1").Value = "CRC"
    oExcelsheet.Range("f2").Formula = " = IF(LEN(A2)=2,(CONCATENATE("'00000",A2)),IF(LEN(A2)=3,CONCATENATE("'0000",A2),IF(LEN(A2)=4,CONCATENATE("'000",A2),IF(LEN(A2)=5,CONCATENATE("'00",A2),IF(LEN(A2)=6,CONCATENATE("'0",A2),A2)))))"


    oExcelFile.DisplayAlerts = False


    oExcelFile.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename:=strFolderPath + "\" + newFileName, FileFormat:=Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False)


    oExcelFile.ActiveWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

    Dim file_count As Integer = File.ReadAllLines(strFolderPath + "\" + newFileName).Length
    MsgBox(file_count)


    oExcelFile.DisplayAlerts = True


    oExcelFile.Quit()


    oExcelFile = Nothing
```

Comment: Use two single quotes, `''`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping single quote in String.Format()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351074/escaping-single-quote-in-string-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have included double quotes (") inside your string literal. The first double quote inside the string is taken to mean the end of the string. It happens to be followed by a single quote which indicate the start of a comment. If you include a double quote inside a string literal, you need to have two of them. Here is the corrected statement (I split it over three lines for readability).

```
oExcelsheet.Range("f2").Formula = "=IF(LEN(A2)=2,(CONCATENATE(""'00000"",A2))," _
  & "IF(LEN(A2)=3,CONCATENATE(""'0000"",A2),IF(LEN(A2)=4,CONCATENATE(""'000"",A2)," _
  & "IF(LEN(A2)=5,CONCATENATE(""'00"",A2),IF(LEN(A2)=6,CONCATENATE(""'0"",A2),A2)))))"
```