# Concatenation with single quote in String.Concat

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMRNNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Concat(Eval("MRNNumber"))%>'>  </asp:Label>
```

It display as 
MRN-01 
MRN-02 
MRN-03 
my requirement is
'MRN-01' 
'MRN-02' 
'MRN-03'

```
Text='<%# String.Concat("'",Eval("MRNNumber"),"'")%>' This gives error!
```

how to do this!

Comment: didnt get your question

Comment: Are you using gridview

Comment: Yes, this is in Gridview and in ItemTemplate.

Comment: @Sakthivel Check with my below answer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Text="<%#(Eval(&quot;MRNNumber&quot;,&quot;'{0}'&quot;))%>"
```

This will be treated as

```
text=Eval("MRNNumber","'{0}'")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Gridview Item formatting](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t110681-gridview-item-formatting.html):

**Method 1:**

Use BoundField, and intercept the GridView's RowDataBound event, in the
RowDataBound event, we can get the Binded Data from the certain GridView
Row's Cell

For **Ex**:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "'" + e.Row.Cells[2].Text + "'";
  }
}
```

**or:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    Label lbl_Name = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblMRNNumber");
    lbl_Name.Text = "'" + lbl_Name.Text + "'";
  }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TemplatePrice">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblMRNNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#  AddDollar(Eval("MRNNumber").ToString()) %>'>  </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

AddDolloar is the helper function defined in page class:

```
protected string AddDollar(string mystr)
{
  return "'" + mystr + "'";
}
```

[**Take a look at this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264414/how-to-use-single-quotes-in-eval-format-string)

Comment: other than code behind can we do this in Eval method in design section?

Comment: @VigneshKumar see my answer , i have just tested it in my code

Comment: @Sakthivel Take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264414/how-to-use-single-quotes-in-eval-format-string