# ASP Grid inside of Bootstrap popover using Eval Tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, popover

I have a ASP Gridview that has a column with a button that opens a popover. Inside the popover I want to populate an ASP Table or ASP Gridview to show hidden related data. I am able to open the popover and it displays hard coded data. But when I want to make the data result dynamic using the Eval() tag the syntax is not able to read the text="<%# Eval('Label1') %>" tags within the string within the object.

The purpose is to load the entire data set and the popover data on one page load. I am wanting to avoid reload if possible.  It seems that it cannot handle the <% within the string, is there a way to handle for this?

Any advice is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Sample code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" 
        runat="server" 
        class="btn btn-info btn-xs"
        Text="+" 
        OnClientClick="return false;" 
        data-toggle="popover" 
        data-trigger="focus"
        TabIndex="0" 
        data-placement="right" 
        title="Owner Change" 
        UseSubmitBehavior="true"
        data-content='<asp:Gridview runat="server" ID="gdvTest">
                      <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Label One">
                          <asp:ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" text="<%# Eval('Label1') %>" />
                          </asp:ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Label Two">
                          <asp:ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" text="<%# Eval('Label2') %>" />
                          </asp:ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                      </Columns>
                    </asp:Gridview>
                  />
```

**Update:** I also attempted to use ASP Table, but my class is not recognizing the ID im trying to use to dynamically populate the Label.

```
...data-content="<asp:Table><asp:TableRow><asp:TableHeaderCell text='TestHeader'><asp:Label runat='server' ID='lblTest' style='color:Red'></asp:TableHeaderCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table></asp:Gridview>"
```

Comment: Where is this `"<%# Eval('Label1') %>"` supposed to take data from? Do you bind this grid view inside popover with any data?

Comment: Yes I bind the data from the class for the large gridview, so I'm assuming I would do the same for the gridview within the popover. I don't think the binding is the problem, but rather the syntax of the Label tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a bit off indeed. Remember that everything inside `<%# %>` should be a valid C#, so `'Label2'` is an invalid literal. To fix that, swap quotes over:

```
text='<%# Eval("Label1") %>'
```

**Update.**
Missed the fact that GridView is itself surrounded by single quotes of `data-content` attribute. Even though this markup looks quite weird, there is a way to make it work, using double quotes everywhere and [escaping appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/264451/728795):

```
text="<%# Eval(&quot;Label1&quot;) %>"
```

Comment: Is this true even if the data-content itself starts with ' also?

Comment: @user3404204, oh, sorry, missed that. I'll amend, hold on

Comment: It is getting closer but I'm end resulting in the popover displaying but the gridview is now just displaying the end of the quote string as "> now. It seems to not like the <%# portion of the code.